# WPF Listbox brake on MVVM when using a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, listbox

I have a `ListBox`, and I bind the `ItemSource` to it using `MVVM Light`. The ItemTemplate is set in the style, it works fine, I won't post that part.

```
<ListBox Name="symbolList"  MouseDoubleClick="listbox1_MouseDoubleClick"  Style="{StaticResource SymbolListStyle}" />
.. in style
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Area, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding SelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I have the `DoubleClick Event`, and corresponfing functions

```
private void listbox1_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ) {
    int index = viewModel.SelectedIndex;
    CloseEvaluating(index == -1);
    if ( index != -1 ) {
        viewModel.IsEvaluating = true;
        ObservedArea area = (ObservedArea) ( symbolList.Items[index] );
        viewModel.EvaluatedArea = Utils.Converter.DeepCopy<ObservedArea>(area);
    }
}
private void ClearLines( ) {
        viewModel.Line1 = new Point();
        viewModel.Line2 = new Point();
        //viewModel.IsPlacingLine = false;
        viewModel.LineNumbers = 0;
}

private void CloseEvaluating( bool reset ) {
        viewModel.IsEvaluating = false;
        viewModel.EvaluatedArea = null;
        if ( reset )
            viewModel.SelectedIndex = -1;
        ListRowSizeUpper.Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
        ListRowSizeLower.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        ClearLines();
}
```

Which does this: Gets the selected `ListItem`, closes the evalulating area, sets `IsEvalating` to true, so the evaluating area shows up again( its needed to be done, so it will resize itself), gets the selected item as an `ObservedArea`, and puts the `EvaluatedArea`, to so its on the screen. This is how it is in action.

Before and after:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACG75.png

Everything is working fine, when I double click on any other `ListItem`, the binding works as intended, and updates the layout with the newly selected area,and  displays the selected graph down there. The problem comes, when I start this thread: 
(Note that the above pictures was taken during running of the thread, the problem comes after 2-5 double clicks.)

```
 private void readAllValues( ThreadPackage pack ) {
            try {
                var resultSet = new libnodave.resultSet();
                libnodave.PDU pdu = pack.Connection.DConnection.prepareReadRequest();
                foreach ( var element in pack.Areas ) {
                    int length = Utils.Converter.GetTypeLength(element.Symbol.Type);
                    pdu.addVarToReadRequest(element.Symbol.Libnod, element.Symbol.DbNumber, element.Symbol.Address, length);
                }
                pack.Connection.DConnection.execReadRequest(pdu, resultSet);

                DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                for ( int i = 0; i < pack.Areas.Count; i++ ) {
                    if ( pack.Connection.DConnection.useResult(resultSet, i) == 0 ) {
                        int value = pack.Areas[i].Symbol.QueryValue(pack.Connection);

                        pack.Areas[i].AddItem(new Item() {
                            Value = value,
                            Time = currentTime
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ) {
                pack.Connection.IsOpen = "Error";
            }
        }

        private void StartMeassureThread( object package ) {
            var pack = (ThreadPackage) package;

            if ( pack.Connection.IsOpen == "Error" || pack.Connection.IsOpen == "Connecting" )
                return;

            try {
                while ( pack.Connection.IsOpen == "Online" && Active ) {
                    readAllValues(pack);

                    lock ( mutex ) {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(( ) => {
                            Messenger.Default.Send<Messages.RefreshGraph>(new Messages.RefreshGraph());
                        });

                        Thread.Sleep(Model.Constants.QuerySleepTime);
                    }
                }

                if ( pack.Connection.IsOpen != "Exit" )
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(( ) => {
                        Messenger.Default.Send<Messages.MeassuringStopped>(new Messages.MeassuringStopped());
                    });
            }
            catch ( Exception ) {
                pack.Connection.IsOpen = "Error";
            }
        }
```

In `ThreadPackage` there is a `Connection`, which represent a connection to a PLC device, and the `Area`, with all of the `ObservedArea` you can see on the pictures(Q0, Q2 ...) `readAllValues` queries data from the PLC, and puts each value to their ObservedArea, with `AddItem` method.

If the thread is not running, the `SelectedIndex` always represent the currently selected values index of the `ListBox`, and the `EvaluatingArea` is showing the selected areas graph. During this thread, the `ListBox` behaves complete different. Despite the `SelectionMode` is set to `Single`, both of the firstly selected item, and the newly selected item is "`selected`", so using `SelectedIndex` as the bound value for the `ListBox's` `SelectedIndex` property, will give me the firstly selected index. Changing the index getting part of the DoubleClick event to this:

```
 int index = -1;
            if ( symbolList.SelectedItems.Count != 0 )
                index = viewModel.Area.IndexOf((ObservedArea) symbolList.SelectedItems[symbolList.SelectedItems.Count - 1]);
```

will get the latest selected item. But don't know why it has multiple selected items anyway. 
After some clicking and changing around a `DispatcherUnhandledException` is thrown, and I catch it in the `App.xaml.cs`. The exception is shown in the picture. The message is: 
An item with the same key has already been added.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMSB5.png

What could be the error, or what am I missing?

Comment: you can only update UI elements from the UI thread

Comment: It's not about upateing UI element, it runs perfectly, since I am updating it with the Dispatcher.Invoke. THe problem is about the selection, and the error coming with it.

Comment: Lists aren't thread-safe (though I think there are newer types - "...Concurrent..." - that are.)  We ran into a similar problem a few months ago and I think we had to lock the code making changes to a list to prevent this problem.  That's just off the top of my head - been a while and I don't remember the details.

Comment: What do you mean lock?

Comment: This: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx  (I think there are now better ways to do this, but this worked for us.)